# Calculate initial value in custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my react app, I have a custom hook `useDataObject()` that computes an object based on the value of another hook, e.g. `useScreenWidth()`. My problem is, that I don't where to place the calculation logic, so the object is ready immediately on the first return:

```
function useScreenWidth() {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);

    return width;
}

function useDataObject() {
    const width = useScreenWidth();
    const [dataObject, setDataObject] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        // Some logic that creates dataObject from width
        const dataObject = {
            firstValue: 2 * width,
            secondValue: width + 10
        };
        setDataObject(dataObject);
    }, [width]);

    return dataObject;
}

export default function App() {
    const dataObject = useDataObject();

    // Can I get rid of this check?
    // Currently needed to prevent "Can not read property firstValue of undefined
    if (!dataObject) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>Data object first value: {dataObject.firstValue}</div>
            <div>Data object second value: {dataObject.secondValue}</div>
        </>
    );
}
```

See this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-rgb-k3fz1)

Because `useDataObject` does not have an initial state I need to wait for the first `useEffect` to finish until I get a valid `dataObject`. This means I need to always include a null check after calls to `useDataObject()`.

What would be the best approach to execute the calculation logic in `useDataObject()` before the first return and then every time the width changes?

One approach I tried was creating an internal function that does the calculation:

```
function useDataObject() {
  const width = useScreenWidth();
  const [dataObject, setDataObject] = useState(calculateDataObject());

  function calculateDataObject() {
    // Some logic that creates dataObject from width
    const dataObject = {
      firstValue: 2 * width,
      secondValue: width + 10
    };
    return dataObject;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setDataObject(calculateDataObject());
  }, [width, calculateDataObject]);

  return dataObject;
}
```

But this looks pretty clunky and confusing. It also gives me a linting error telling me I should use `useCallback()`. Isn't there a more straight forward way?
Thank you!

Comment: Your `useDataObject` hook seems a little bit useless in this case, I mean as a hook. It looks like a pretty regular function. So, you can use it as in your second example but as the linter warns you either use a `useCallback` for it or move the function in your `useEffect`.

Comment: `useDataObject` has to subscribe to a hook. That means it has to be a hook itself, or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. For a second I thought you were merging the hooks. IF at a point if your data object will be `null`, somehow you should check for it I guess.

Comment: The way you propose is the best solution I see: 1. It includes `useScreenWidth` inside the hook itself, this is correct as you are not using it outside (in the component), 2. `calculateDataObject` has to be run in the initial state definition, otherwise you need to do the check in the component for the initial nullish value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. I found using the `useMemo()` hook (see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo))  instead of `useState()` + `useEffect()` is a possible solution for my scenario:

```
function useDataObject() {
  const width = useScreenWidth();

  return useMemo(() => {
    // Do some calculation with width
    const dataObject = {
      firstValue: 2 * width,
      secondValue: width + 10
    };
    return dataObject;
  }, [width]);
}
```

[Full example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wood-kyy9f)

- The hook returns the computed `dataObject` immediately.
- Every time `[width]` changes the calculation is redone and the new value is returned.
- No code is duplicated or executed too often.

I can not guarantee that there is no better solution, but for my purpose it does exactly what I need.
(Of course one could also integrate the `useScreenWidth` hook into the `useDataObject` Hook. But in my project, I need the `useScreenWidth` separately.)